# Boolean to integer conversion

Tags: c#

Is there a way to covert from bool to integer without a conditional statement (e.g., if-statement)?

```
int intValue = boolValue ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain the answer is *no*. Have you tried an explicit conversion, via a cast?

Comment: Just curious, what don't you like about that statement?

Comment: Conditional logic always contributes to the Cyclomatic complexity of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not. You may hide this conditional behind additional method calls like `Convert.ToInt`, or prefer a different syntax like an actual `if` but in the end, somewhere, there will be your conditional.

Comment: I was going to propose a counter-example with a Dictionary/lookup but one can always argue the "actually `if` but in the end" down to pretty much darn any level; or at least well below C#.

Comment: In a previous comment I suggested to simply cast a pointer to the bool to a pointer to int and dereference it in order to obtain an int value (in an `unsafe` method). But the sizes of bool and int differ, cf. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf.aspx. As far as I can see such a cast wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Despite the fact that **nvoigt**'s answer is perfectly correct I can give you a few more examples JUST FOR FUN

NEVER! NEVER USE THIS CODE! IT IS PROVIDED JUST FOR FUN OR TO RESOLVE A DISPUTE WITH A (GOOD) FRIEND!)

At first method `GetHashCode` does the magic (as an implementation detail):

```
bool b = true;
int i = b.GetHashCode();
```

If you want some more esoteric approach.. hm.. you're welcome):

```
bool b = true;
int i = ~(b.ToString()[0] / 2) & 1;
```

REMEMBER! NEVER!

Comment: I like it. Do you know whether Convert.ToInt32(boolValue) uses some sort of bit manipulation or conditional logic? I am a bit lazy to use  .net reflector.

Comment: Try ILSpy :) : if (!value) return 0; return 1;

Comment: This is the only sensible answer on this question, at least if b.GetHashCode() is inlined ...   Other responders do not appear to understand the OP's point, i.e. avoiding a conditional

Answer (score 2):

```
int intValue = Convert.ToInt32(boolValue));
```

Comment: explain your answer briefly.

Comment: @Ravimallya What needs to be explained in it?

Comment: do You have to import convert? where do you get that from

Comment: @KitChaos its part of the `System` namespace. Mostly it's already imported. But if it's not, you can do it by adding `using System` at the top of the file. [Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=net-8.0)

Answer (score 1):

Use  `Convert.ToInt32(boolValue)`

Answer (score 0):

Something to play around with, though I don't recommend it (requires Unsafe code enabled for project):

```
internal static class Extensions
{
    unsafe static public Int32 ToInt32(this bool value)
    {
        void* b = &value;
        return *(Int32*)b;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var b = true;
Console.WriteLine($"{b}\t{b.ToInt32()}");

b = false;
Console.WriteLine($"{b}\t{b.ToInt32()}");
```

Displays:

```
True    1
False   0
```

It's slower than the ?: operator, however:

```
var b = true;
int i = 0;
int iterations = 100_000_000;

Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int ndx = 0; ndx < iterations; ndx++)
{
    i = b ? 1 : 0;
    b = !b;
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"?:\t{sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} {i}");

b = true;
sw.Restart();
for (int ndx = 0; ndx < iterations; ndx++)
{
    i = b.ToInt32();
    b = !b;
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"cast\t{sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} {i}");
```

My system reports 85ms for the ?: operation, and 180ms for the unsafe method.